# Why is mysqli class missing while being installed?

Tags: php, mysqli, raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian

I'm on Raspbian 9.

I installed php and php-mysql

```
>sudo sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php7.0-mysql is already the newest version (7.0.30-0+deb9u1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

But my php script throw an error, stating myscli class is not available

```
>php prodDataSender.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /home/pi/prodDataSender.php:12
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/pi/prodDataSender.php on line 12
```

Here is the really simple line causing the error :

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);
```

Here is a the php -i grep :

```
>php -i | grep mysql
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
pi@valrb2:~ $
```

I tried :

reload/restart apache2
reboot
Removing / Installing again php / php-mysql

Nothing works.

I don't know what to search now.

Edit :

If I add :

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

I get :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_connect in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /home/pi/prodDataSender.php:12
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/pi/prodDataSender.php on line 12
```

Comment: Did you add the uncomment the mysql extensions in the php settings?

Comment: I never had to add anything in the php.ini file for a simple apt php / php-mysql installation. What am I suppose to add ?

Comment: @iizno did you upgrade from a previous version of PHP where you were using the mysql_ api by any chance? If so, then that may be the reason and it's still using the same settings from another .ini file. `phpinfo()` will show you which one it's using.

Comment: Are you working with an autoloader? Try `\mysqli` in that case

Comment: phpinfo() shows nothing about mysql. But it's hard to tell, I don't have a browser access, only cli.

Comment: @MarvinFischer I tried with a \ and with use mysqli; none worked.

Comment: Can you check the php.ini file for this line `extension=mysqli.so` if theres a `;` infront of that, remove it

Comment: There is no extension=mysqli.so in my php.ini file.

Comment: I tried to add it, See my edit.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/784629/php-mysqli-so-undefined-symbol-mysqlnd-connect-in-unknown-on-line-0 basicly says load mysqlnd before mysqli

Comment: mysqli module got somehow disabled, to fix run phpenmod mysqli
or 
run `sudo phpenmod mysqli` or reinstall php7.0-mysql with: `sudo apt-get purge php7.0-mysql && sudo apt-get install php-mysql`
see the output of `php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep -i mysqli`
don't forget to  `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @sothish The "purge" one did the trick, thank you. Please create an answer so I can validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reinstalling php7.0-mysql with purge works: `sudo apt-get purge php7.0-mysql && sudo apt-get install php-mysql` Please validate the output `php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep -i mysqli`